# how to reference which particle system the current object is using?

Tags: python, particles

is there a way in python to reference which particle system an object is referring to?
for example, I have a mesh named 'cube' with a particle system called 'cube_particle'. if I delete it, then I append the cube again, the second 'cube' would have a particle system called 'cube_particle.001'. if there are multiple objects, it could become quite a mess to reference which one is using which.

in python, bpy.context.active_object.particle_systems["cube_particle"] can only get object depended property such as bpy.context.object.particle_systems["cube_particle"].child_seed = 0
whereas bpy.data.particles["cube_particle.001"].child_nbr = 10, it is through bpy.data, not active_obj,

I am looking for some kind of operation to find a link between active_object.particle_systems[A] to data.particles[B].
for example, cube.001 's particle system cube_particle is currently linked to data.particles["cube_particle.002"]

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

active_object.particle_systems[A].**settings.name** would return data.particles[B] in this case.